# Opening AppExchange in sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, appexchange

I am trying to install an app through **AppExchange** in sandbox.

When I oepn an app and click **Get It Now**, it takes me to [login.salesforce.com](http://login.salesforce.com).

[image]

I tried changing *login* to *test* in url but not successful.

After clicking on **Get It Now** it should show option to **Install in Sandbox** or **Install in Production**, but I am not seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, To install the solutions from app exchange first you have to login to AppExchange( to login you can use your production credentials /dev org credentials )

See the below screenshot(
[image]

once you login you  can click "**Get It Now**" button then you will get to **Install in Sandbox** or **Install in Production**,
see below 
[image]

if you are directly click on  "**Get It Now**" button it will navigate you to login page, from there also you can log in and again you can click "**Get It Now**" button.

Comment: I think they changed something because I don't get this option either. I get redirected to a trailhead login, and I can't find a way to log into my sandbox from there.